# Dumping Text of Locals Window in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to dump the entire text content of the Locals window (programmatically if possible, but the UI command to do this would be equally helpful) into a separate file and/or the Windows clipboard? (This isn't my day-to-day development tool, so apologies if this is an obvious/dumb question).

A program I'm working on is throwing the following exception after making a SOAP call

> - $exception  {"Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'login'."} System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException}

I'm guessing that, somewhere in the Locals window (where I can see the exception), the actual message body that can't be deserialized has been included.  I'd like to examine this message body to debug my program.

Rather than click-scan-click-scan-click-scan through the nested tree window, I'd like to be able to fully expand the tree(s) in the Locals window, and then view the dumped output in a text editor.

Is this possible using Visual Studio?

Comment: Turns out you can access locals via StudioShell. I've expanded my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about programmatically, but I was able to do it manually.

- Selecting something in the Locals windows
- `Ctrl` + `A` to select everything in the Locals windows
- `Ctrl` + `C` to copy

Then in my text editor, I simply pasted it... but it was rather ugly (it produced tab-separated columns). Luckily, I have [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) which can handle transforming that into a more readable result (I used the `Convert to fixed column` feature).

Now, if you have [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) you can have all sorts of fun! StudioShell basically turns you entire solution in to navigable file system. Using that, you can navigate to 
`dte:\debugger\DebuggedProcesses\DemoSolution.vshost.exe\5300\current` (5300 is a thread number) and just to `ls locals` to get your locals for current stack frame on that thread.